# DirectWrite align text center

Tags: c++, text, directx, direct2d, directwrite

I am trying to align center the text I have to draw. I use [ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawTextLayout method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The problemn is that if I set the text horizontal alignment to `DWRITE_TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEADING` (the default value) the text is drawn proberly, but if I change this value to `DWRITE_TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER` the text is shifted right.

The example string is

```
Internal Amazing 
Scupper
```

Following are the outcomes (the first is alignment leading):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just a quick guess: Did you check that the maxwidth your layout box isn't too broad, so the center would end there at the right?

Comment: @Gnietschow how can I set the max size of my layout box equals to the area of the the rectangle that contains my text? That is, how can I get the bounds of my text area?

Comment: @Gnietschow By the way, your comment is correct, please write your answer.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with directwrite, but it seems that you can compute the minimum width your text needs with the method `DetermineMinWidth` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316723%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of your `IDWriteTextLayout`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My comment as an answer (yeah, guessed right :)):

> Just a quick guess: Did you check that the maxwidth your layout box
>   isn't too broad, so the center would end there at the right?

The `IDWriteTextLayout` used by `ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawTextLayout` method defines a maximum width of the layout box, which determines where the text is centered. It can be manipulated by the [methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316718%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the interface ([GetMaxWidth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316781(v=vs.85).aspx) and [SetMaxWidth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371511(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Comment: Additionally the width is a parameter when you first call CreateTextLayout.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the text layout, you cannot change the width and height to something greater afterwards. You should use max screen coords when creating the layout then change the max width and height to the desired size. You should use render_tgt->DrawText(...) method for this example or release and recreate the layout interface every time the text, font name, and a lot of other various things like typography are changed. I created an array of layout and typography events that can be reapplied to the layout interface every time it is recreated. You do not need to recreate the layout for font size, since you can resize the text or individual characters with the layout interface

```
// Set the layout to maximum screen size
FLOAT maxX = (FLOAT)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFULLSCREEN); // * XD2D::pix_to_dips.x;
FLOAT maxY = (FLOAT)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFULLSCREEN); // * XD2D::pix_to_dips.y;

XS_DWRITE_DEV_FACTORY->CreateTextLayout
(
    dstring,
    dlength,
    (*pp_txt_format),
    maxX,
    maxY,
    pp_txt_layout
);

// Resize to the requested size or minimum allowed size
(*pp_txt_layout)->SetMaxWidth(max(req_xsize, (*pp_txt_layout)->GetFontSize()));
(*pp_txt_layout)->SetMaxHeight(max(req_ysize, (*pp_txt_layout)->GetFontSize()));
```